# What is the effect of compression on a MapReduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The following has been documented in a white paper from Microsoft:

> Compression will help if the input source files are very large (for example, over 500 GB) and you want to run MapReduce jobs repeatedly against the same input data.

So, we should use compression *if the input files are very large*, as it saves disk I/O and network bandwidth.

But, I cannot understand how "running a MapReduce job repeatedly against same input data" will help with the performance of compressing and decompressing? Compression should have same performance even if the data is different every time.

Comment: can you also point microsoft white paper link ?

Comment: It's simply math, if you read compressed multiple times your net-saving is much bigger than reading uncompressed once.

Comment: @Ram, I do not have link. If possible I can upload it.  But with Question ,as per my understanding, we cannot attach documents with question.

Comment: @Thomas, You are right net-saving of compressed data will be better than un-compressed one, but - For Ex. A compressed file "FILE1" processed 4 times a day and another compressed file "FILE2" processed 1 time a day. Same map reduce program runs on both files at different times of a day. As per "running a MapReduce job repeatedly against same input data" we should compress FILE 1 and not FILE2. What you suggest?

Comment: "Once per day" is still a repeated process. You should compress both of them in this case. On the contrary, if you download an uncompressed file once and only read it once, there is little sense in having an additional process compressing the data because there is no/little saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on the what kind of compression logic is used to compress the files. Following is the information I found on internet.

http://comphadoop.weebly.com/

File compression brings two major benefits: 
a.  it reduces the space needed to store files, 
b.  it speeds up data transfer across the network or to or from disk. When dealing with large volumes of data, both of these savings can be significant, so it pays to carefully consider how to use compression in Hadoop.

Reasons to compress:
a) Data is mostly stored and not frequently processed. It is usual DWH scenario. In this case space saving can be much more significant then processing overhead 
b) Compression factor is very high and thereof we save a lot of IO. 
c) Decompression is very fast (like Snappy) and thereof we have a some gain with little price 
d) Data already arrived compressed

Reasons not to compress:

a) Compressed data is not splittable. Have to be noted that many modern format are built with block level compression to enable splitting and other partial processing of the files. 
b) Data is created in the cluster and compression takes significant time. Have to be noted that compression usually is much more CPU intensive then decompression.

All compression algorithms exhibit a space/time trade-off: faster compression and decompression speeds usually come at the expense of smaller space savings. Meaning, faster compression (in terms of time) means files are relatively bigger (not much of a benefit on space). Slower compression means, the compressed files are very small.
2. Common input format

[various compression formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNhnl.png)

Comment: Could you please help in reason out- "running a MapReduce job repeatedly against same input data"  is one of criteria to decide whether data should be compressed or not.